# SKviewでのSegueを用いた画面遷移

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, spritekit

現在、Xcode（Swift)でアプリ開発をしています。
SKviewから別のUIViewへ画面遷移をしたい為、以下のサイトを参考にコードを書いています。

[SpriteKit で segue を使って別の UIView に遷移する方法](https://hawksnowlog.blogspot.com/2017/09/use-segue-on-spritekit.html)

ここで、下記のコードを入力した結果、エラーが出てしまいました。

**ソースコード:**

```
//「戻る」ボタンの動作
    @objc func onClickBackButton(sender : UIButton){          
    if let view = self.view {
          let vc = view.window?.rootViewController;
        vc?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "to_top", sender: nil)
     }
}
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Receiver (<Smoquit.ViewController: 0x7f8eb3f0ed30>) has no segue with identifier 'to_top'
```

segueの識別子は'to_top'に設定しております。
何故、上記のエラーが出るのかご教授いただけると幸いです。
また、別のSKviewからUIviewへの遷移方法がございましたらご提案いただけるとありがたいです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: リンク先の記事を含め、「別のUIView」へではなく「別のUIViewController」ですね。UIViewとUIViewControllerは全く異なる概念のものですから、区別するようにしてください。ご使用のコードで`let vc = view.window?.rootViewController`は、該当のSKView(あるいはSKScene)が`rootViewController`内に表示されているときにしか動作しません。簡単にいうと「`vc`には自分が表示されているViewControllerを取り出さないといけない」ということになります。これ以上具体的なことはもっと詳しい情報を追加してもらわないとなんとも言えません。

Comment: 質問さんと、共に原因を探り、検証し、解決策を見つけていくことはできますが、「ご教授」はできません。そのためには、あまりに情報が少なすぎます。もし「原因はこれ、解決方法はこれ」という形の回答でなく、試行錯誤しながら、解決への道のりを、共に進んでいくような形でよければ、回答欄に書き込みしようと思います。いかがですか？ともあれ、`let vc =view.window?.rootViewController`の行の次に`if vc.storyboard == nil { print("This view controller has no storyboard.") } else { print("This view controller has a storyboard.") }`を追加して、実行してみてください。